# Extracting values from arbitrary un-Known Nats

Tags: haskell, types, type-constraints, type-families, type-level-computation

Given the type-level list function (from [this blog post](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-16-type-level-functions-using-closed-type-families.html))

```
type family Length (xs :: [*]) :: Nat where
    Length '[] = 0
    Length (_ ': xs) = 1 + Length xs
```

The value extraction of 'hard-coded' type-list lengths works as expected

```
t1 :: Integer
t1 = natVal (Proxy :: Proxy (Length '[Int]))
```

And `t1 = 1`. However, making a function to get the value from an arbitrary list seems to fail.

```
t2 :: forall (xs :: [*]). Proxy xs -> Integer
t2 _ = natVal (Proxy :: Proxy (Length xs))
```

Gives the error

```
    • No instance for (KnownNat (Length xs))
        arising from a use of ‘natVal’
```

Which seems unfortunate but reasonable since only the literals are 'Known'. However, forcing the constraint to be satisfied as follows results in complaints about ambiguous types.

```
unsafeKnownConstr :: c :~: (KnownNat n :: Constraint)
unsafeKnownConstr = unsafeCoerce Refl

t3 :: forall (xs :: [*]). Proxy xs -> Integer
t3 _ = case Proxy :: Proxy (Length xs) of
         p@(_ :: Proxy l) -> case unsafeKnownConstr @(KnownNat l) of
                             Refl -> natVal @l p
```

Specifically,

```
    • Could not deduce (KnownNat n0) arising from a use of ‘natVal’
      from the context: KnownNat n0 ~ KnownNat (Length xs)
        bound by a pattern with constructor:
                   Refl :: forall k (a :: k). a :~: a,
                 in a case alternative
...
      The type variable ‘n0’ is ambiguous
```

What is GHC (8.10.4) complaining about here? Alternatively, is there another way to extract these un-Known Nats?

Comment: One could try `t2 :: forall (xs :: [*]). KnownNat (Length xs) => Proxy xs -> Integer`. In your case you would need `unsafeKnownConstr @(KnownNat l) @(Length xs)` but I don't think forcing the coercion will get you far -- I expect that to crash at runtime. Unsafe code is unsafe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
t4 :: forall n xs. (n ~ Length xs, KnownNat n) => Proxy xs -> Integer
t4 _ = natVal $ Proxy @n
```

This says your *callers* have to know the type level list `xs` well enough to fully resolve `Length xs` to fixed value, for which they'll be able to produce a `KnownNat` instance.<sup>1</sup> But inside `t4` you get to operate on lists you don't statically know.

```
λ t4 $ Proxy @[Int, Char, Bool]
3
it :: Integer
```

---

Your attempt didn't work because `unsafeKnownConstr` has type `forall c n. c :~: KnownNat n`. It promises that for any constraint `c` you like, it can prove that the constraint is equal to `KnownNat n` for any `n` you like.

Quite apart from how that is obviously a false promise, when you use `unsafeKnownConstr @(KnownNat l)` you're only setting `c`. `n` is still a type variable that can be instantiated to anything. GHC doesn't know what to pick for `n`; that's the ambiguous type variable GHC is complaining about. Effectively you've lied and told it that any arbitrarily chosen `n` is equal to the length of the list, but you haven't actually chosen the `n` to use, so GHC has no way of telling *what* `KnownNat` dictionary you want to consider (falsely) the `KnownNat` dictionary for `Length xs`.

If you fix the second type parameter for `unsafeKnownConstr`, then you can get something like this to compile:

```
t3 :: forall (xs :: [*]). Proxy xs -> Integer
t3 _ = case Proxy :: Proxy (Length xs) of
         p@(_ :: Proxy l) -> case unsafeKnownConstr @(KnownNat l) @17928 of
                             Refl -> natVal @l p
```

Which then allows you to do this in GHCI:

```
λ t3 $ Proxy @[Int, Char, Bool]
17928
it :: Integer
```

Whatever value you choose, though, unsafely coercing `KnownNat` constraints isn't going to be very useful to you because they do actually contain information: the value that is known for the `Nat`!

---

<sup>1</sup> Or they too can punt on solving it and pass the constraints on to their own callers via their own types.

Comment: Thanks! So it sounds like the caller somehow has to have proof that the constraint is already solved? That is, even though we can get a `Nat`, we can never prove from it alone that it is `Known`?

Comment: @Lawrence (1/2) When you write a function polymorphic in some type variable `n` of kind `Nat`, then your function has to work for all possible Nats. But "work for all Nats" is meant in the same way that something polymorphic in a type variable of kind `Type` has to work for all types; the type variable has to be treated as a black box and the code must work regardless of what's in there. You can't test what the type is and do different things, and you can't see what the nat is to do different things (such as get different `Integer` values out of `natVal`. This allows efficient compilation...

Comment: @Lawrence (2/2) ... via type erasure. The types are used to check the code can only do type-safe things, but are then discarded. At runtime, only the code is present, so the specific `Nat` value your type was instantiated with just isn't available to inspect anyway. `KnownNat` is what allows you to circumvent type erasure and have the specific `Nat` values available at runtime (that's what's "known" about them). I believe the `KnownNat` dictionary just **is** the value.

Comment: @Lawrence All that said, yes, the type of my `t4` just says "you can only call me when you know the length of the type-level list". Frequently I find that's not a big problem because you can just propagate the constraints back to where the type level list was constructed and you DID know it's length. You have to add messier constraints to types along the way, but the compiler can hopefully do the dictionary passing for you without too much help e.g. in my example calling `t4` I just instantiated the list; the compiler measured and propagated the length on its own just fine.